# thread safe search-and-add

Tags: linux, thread-safety, linked-list, kernel

I need to be able to do the following:

1. search a linked list.
2. add a new node to the list in case it's not found.
3. be thread safe and use rwlock since it's read mostly list.

The issue i'm having is when I promote from read_lock to write_lock I need to search the list again just to make sure some other thread wasn't waiting on a write_lock while I was doing the list search holding the read_lock.

Is there a different way to achieve the above without doing a double list search (perhaps a seq_lock of some sort)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the linked list to a sorted linked list. When its time to add a new node you can check again to see if another writer has added an equivalent node while you were acquiring the lock by inspecting only two nodes, instead of searching the entire list. You will spend a little more time on each node insertion because you need to determine the sorted order of the new node, but you will save time by not having to search the entire list. Overall you will probably save a lot of time.